# Set form names with javascript loop

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with which a user can dynamically add text inputs. This generates a form with multiple text inputs that have the same name. If this form is submitted they overwrite each other. To solve this I need change the names so that they are appended with an incremented prefix when the form is submitted. Can anyone help?

Example of form (once three inputs have been added):

```
<form action="" method="post">
<td class="recipe-table__cell">
<input id="answer" name="the_answer" type="text" value="" >
<input id="answer" name="the_answer" type="text" value="" >
<input id="answer" name="the_answer" type="text" value="" >
</td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Desired Post output on submission:

Array ( [1-answer] => test  [2-answer] => ok [3-answer] => nice)

rather than Array ( [answer] => test )

Comment: You should not have more than one id per page, even before JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select all of the elements that you want to add the attribute for. This can be done with **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**.

Second, loop over those elements.

Third, use [**`.setAttribute()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to change the `name` attribute to append the index from the loop.

Note that you'll also want to increment the `ID` attribute, as you can't have duplicate IDs on the same page. You'll also want to swap your `<td>` elements for `<div>` elements to both allow `.querySelectAll()` to work correctly, and ensure valid markup.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("form div input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].setAttribute("id", "answer" + i);
  inputs[i].setAttribute("name", "the_answer" + i);
  console.log(inputs[i]); // Added purely to show the change
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="recipe-table__cell">
    <input id="answer" name="the_answer" type="text" value="">
    <input id="answer" name="the_answer" type="text" value="">
    <input id="answer" name="the_answer" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps! :)